# Postgres window function to number partitions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Similar to how `ROW_NUMBER` and `RANK` apply numbers to rows within a partition, I want to  apply a sequential number to each partition, with each number within the partition being the same.

For example, given the following data;

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_data (
    id serial, 
    group_id int not null, 
    item_name varchar(20) not null
);

INSERT INTO test_data (
    group_id, 
    item_name
)
VALUES 
    (1, 'car'),
    (1, 'van'),
    (1, 'motorbike'),
    (3, 'helicopter'),
    (3, 'plane'),
    (6, 'boat'),
    (6, 'submarine');

SELECT group_id, item_name FROM test_data;
```

| group_id | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car |
| 1 | van |
| 1 | motorbike |
| 3 | helicopter |
| 3 | plane |
| 6 | boat |
| 6 | submarine |

I want to partition these results by the `group_id`, and have each distinct `group_id` to be sequential, with all matching `group_id`s having the same value, i.e.

| group_id | item_name | group_running_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 1 |
| 1 | van | 1 |
| 1 | motorbike | 1 |
| 3 | helicopter | 2 |
| 3 | plane | 2 |
| 6 | boat | 3 |
| 6 | submarine | 3 |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zF5-5Upd)

[`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-dense_rank-function/) does this:

```
SELECT 
    group_id, 
    item_name,
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY group_id) as group_running_no
FROM test_data;
```